# admin privileges in php

Tags: php, admin

I have a PHP script that is supposed to let a user view a page based on user_level. if the user level is set to 1..allow the user to view the page. if not, then redirect them to index.php..for some reason it's not working. It gives me the message, "You are not allowed to access this page". It gives me that message no matter who is logged in, admin or regular user. Any ideas?

```
<?php
include 'init.php';
include('core/init.inc.php');

var_dump($_SESSION)

if(!logged_in()){
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_level'])) {
echo 'You are not allowed to access this page. Click <a href="index.php">here</a> to go back to the home page';
exit();
}elseif(1 == (int)$_SESSION['user_level']){
header('Location: create_album.php');
exit;
}


include 'template/header.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`isset` return a boolean, remove it.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_level'])) {
  echo 'You are not allowed to access this page. Click <a href="index.php">here</a> to go back to the home page';
  exit();
}elseif(1 == (int)$_SESSION['user_level'])){
  header('Location: create_album.php');
  exit;
}
```

Comment: @TechGuy24 Try the code i posted, it check the isset `user_level` first.

Comment: it still displays the you are not allowed message no matter the user level

Comment: @TechGuy24 Please do `var_dump($_SESSION)` and check the content first.

Answer (score 1):

`isset($_SESSION['user_level'])` is the problem.

The PHP function `isset` returns a bool value, which you are testing against.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `isset()` there. It is a `boolean` and not integer. Instead, you can do this way:

Replace

```
if(1 !==(int)(isset($_SESSION['user_level']))) {
```

With

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_level']) && $_SESSION['user_level'] == 1) {
```

Comment: I don't understand why my question was closed..I read the FAQ..I thought this site was for specific questions that "I" as a poster had an issue with that needed help with..I was getting somewhere with everyone's help. So I don't understand what the problem was?..